# Android source checkout specific package

Tags: android

I wish to download specifica packaged app from Android source, I'm trying:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/ -b android-4.1.1_r4
```

I get: error: revision android-4.1.1_r4 in manifests not found.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git
```